# WPF - Bind two strings from .resx and from VM in DataGrid column header

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

How to bind two strings from `.resx` file and from `ViewModel` into `DataGrid` column header. the below code only bind the string from the Resources file.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Length}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Length}" />
            <Run Text="{Binding LengthUnit}" />
        </TextBlock>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

VM:

```
public string LengthUnitName {
    get { return _lengthUnitName; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _lengthUnitName, value); }
}
```

Comment: Where is the LengthUnit property defined?

Comment: @mm8 It's a property in the ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `HeaderTemplate`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Length}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Length}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].LengthUnit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

If the `LengthUnit` property is defined in the view model you could bind like this:

```
<Run Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.LengthUnit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: It didn't work, I have added a converter just to debug and check what values i'm receiving from the view model, but it never reaches the converter code. I tried the both ways you provided but neither worked. I also set the LengthUnit from the constructor to make sure I have it set correctly but didn't work as well.

Comment: Did you really set the Header*Template* to a DataTemplate?

Comment: Oh! ,sorry my bad, didn't pay attention to the HeaderTemplate :P